# How to stop MS Teams chat from altering messages? It adds non-breaking space chr(160) where none existed

Tags: microsoft-teams

Regardless of my line endings setting (CRLF or LF), when I copy/paste code into MS Teams chat, then the recipient (or myself for that matter) copy it from the chat conversation back into a text editor, the process introduces ascii character 160 (non-breaking space). This makes sharing code snippets impossible. Is there any way to prevent this? My govt agency has MS Teams version 1.0.

Is there a way to stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you send code to others, you can avoid this if you click the format option and choose the “code snippet” button (</>).

Then when they select/copy/paste, it will be “as is”.

[link with graphic instructions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/447357/cannot-copy-a-specfic-text-from-code-block-in-team)